# How to Execute the wget script from the ESGF CORDEX Data using Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, wget

I have been trying to download, near future climatic data, I have wget scripts that I have downloaded Cordex data from  the ESGF website, but I am struggling to download them using the Cygwin tool, because I am using a windows , but it is always giving me this error :

pr_AFR-44_NCC-NorESM1-M_rcp85_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_mon_200601-201012.nc ...Downloading
ERROR : http request to OpenID Relying Party service failed.
download failed
i have input the correct Openid and the correct password
what could i be doing wrong ?
[THIS IS THE IMAGE OF THE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU8E2.png)

Comment: the error says you are missing wget, have you installed the wget package ?

Comment: @matzeri i have installed it, mybe you can just refer me to a link to download and install

Comment: use the cygwin setup to install any cygwin package. https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages

Comment: @matzeri thanks for your feed back thus far it has been super helpful,, but if you can https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU8E2.png look at this revised problem, i have installed the wget, now the problem is something else,  is it normal that when i enter my password in the cygwin nothing is showing?