# how to execute the wget script using cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I have been trying to download, near future climatic data, I have wget scripts that I have downloaded Cordex data from the ESGF website, but I am struggling to execute them for download using the Cygwin tool,(because I am using a windows) , but it is always giving me this error :
pr_AFR-44_NCC-NorESM1-M_rcp85_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_mon_200601-201012.nc ...Downloading
ERROR : http request to OpenID Relying Party service failed.
download failed
i have input the correct Openid and the correct password
what could i be doing wrong ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2kFj.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Execute the wget script from the ESGF CORDEX Data using Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61599162/how-to-execute-the-wget-script-from-the-esgf-cordex-data-using-cygwin)

Comment: @matzeri no not yet!, but i hoping

Comment: Did you get this resolved?